# Issue Deploying Heroku App - RQ Worker: wrong number of arguments for 'HSET' command

Tags: heroku, worker, python-rq, heroku-pipelines, heroku-redis

Modifying an app based on [this example](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-custom-angular-directive-with-d3/), I am having a problem when deploying my updated Heroku app during initialization of the web.1 dyno.

Everything is working fine in my development envr; when I start the 'app' and 'worker' executables directly, I can access the working app from 127.0.0.1:5000

I already have the postgresql and redistogo addons created as part of the app...

heroku config file

```
=== app Config Vars
APP_SETTINGS:  config.StagingConfig
DATABASE_URL:  postgres://[points-to-AWS-EC2].compute-1.amazonaws.com:[port]/[identifier]
REDISTOGO_URL: redis://redistogo:[identifier]@pike.redistogo.com:[port]/
```

Procfile

```
web: bash heroku.sh
```

heroku.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn app:app --daemon
python worker.py
```

app.py

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime
import json
import re
import operator
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from requests import get, exceptions as rx
import nltk
from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job
from validators import url as vurl

from worker import conn

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='app-templates/')
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

db = SQLAlchemy(app)    
q = Queue(connection=conn)


def worker_task(url):
    '''
    takes website url and ...
```

worker.py

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['default']
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for tracking worker job in a terminal
    # assumptions: redis-server is running
    try:
        with Connection(conn):
            worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
--->>>      worker.work()         <<<---
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{str(e)}")
```

During the dyno startup, I get the following errors:

> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>
> heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bash heroku.sh`
>
> app[web.1]: **Command # 2 (HSET rq:worker:2bd1d3d3a7f04d2fb7a09b34786689bf 
>   birth 2020-05-23T11:28:04.485474Z 
>   last_heartbeat 2020-05-23T11:28:04.485474Z
>   queues default pid 11 
>   hostname b428750b-5d7f-4837-b9c2-b2195e234978
>   version 1.4.1 python_version 3.7.4 (default, Sep 12 2019, 01:19:52)**
>
> app[web.1]: [GCC 7.4.0]) of pipeline caused error: wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
>
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
>
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Im fairly confident that the error is in the highlighted `worker.work()` line from the worker.py file, because I get the same error when I run `heroku run python worker.py` (or directly copying those lines into the `heroku run python` REPL interpreter)

Comment: edit: Ive replicated the error via manual redis-cli input and identified that the last HSET tuple input `(default, Sep 12 2019, 01:19:52)` seems to be causing the error, but I cannot track down where that piece of data is originating...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I fixed it by downgrading my version of rq from 1.4.1 to 1.3.0.

Comment: thanks @Benjamin, I just resolved it separately by using v1.2.2

note: this issue appears to be tracked in [rq-git-issue-1256](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/1256)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** was an issue with my package versions...

the original example I was using had the following package version dependencies:

```
redis = "==3.4.1"
rq = "==1.2.2"
```

but I was just using the most recently updated packages `= "*"` for both, and when I originally deployed the package in Heroku, it installed RQ version "1.4.0", but then (apparently) when my new app was deployed, the Heroku installer used the latest 1.4.1 package, which broke during the worker.work() method...

Worker RQ v 1.4.0 output:

```
{
  'connection': Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=pike.redistogo.com,port=10038,db=0>>>, 
'hostname': 'e868b6d3-70b4-4e17-98c2-b96aae04d9a8', 
'pid': 39, 
'job_class': <class 'rq.job.Job'>, 
'queue_class': <class 'rq.queue.Queue'>, 'version': '1.4.0',
**'python_version': '3.7.4 (default, Sep 12 2019, 01:19:52) \n[GCC 7.4.0]',** 
**'serializer': <module 'pickle' from '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py'>,**
'name': '05c7af34c21f44f0b4374b40525779af', 
'queues': [Queue('default')], 
'_exc_handlers': [], ... ... 
}
```

Worker RQ v1.4.1 output:

```
{
'connection': Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=pike.redistogo.com,port=11022,db=0>>>,
'hostname': '19a476fa-b4e6-4e63-b40e-ac8779ae0f9e', 
'pid': 39, 
'job_class': <class 'rq.job.Job'>, 
'queue_class': <class 'rq.queue.Queue'>, 
'version': '1.4.1', 
**'python_version': '3.7.4 (default, Sep 12 2019, 01:19:52) \n[GCC 7.4.0]',**
**'serializer': <class 'rq.serializers.DefaultSerializer'>,**
'name': 'b63389b3499f4d73be889a33f3777b46', 
'queues': [Queue('default')], 
'_exc_handlers': [], ... ... 
}
```

You can see a difference in the 'serializer' key between the two, possibly causing the HSET exception that was being throw...

Reverting to RQ v1.2.2 solved the issue for me; I probably could have used the same v1.4.0...